# Is that normal to train properly with 2 sets and/or 2 diff losses function?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I have 2 train sets: one with label and one with no label.

When training, i’m simultaneously loading one batch from a labelled set, then calculating using the first loss function; and then, one batch from unlabeled set, calculating using the using the other function. Finally I sum them (2 losses) and `loss.backward()` .

Does this way work ? it’s quite uncommon in my mind so just ask if the engine know how to back-propagate properly (not wrong)?
Thank you.

Comment: I got an answer from pytorch forum. It's ok to do so.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: why not ? autograd inside pytorch framework is programming. how do you consider this is not related directly to programming while lot of user using pytorch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer from pytorch forum discussion. Autograd engine in pytorch work well and correctly with 2 or more different loss function so we don't need to worry about its accuracy.
Thanks